# Load items with ajax in div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm currently using the following javascript to load items in a a few div's:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'load.php?type=divA',
        cache: false,     
        success: function(data){
        $('#divA').html(data); 
        }
    });   
    $.ajax({
        url: 'load.php?type=divB',
        cache: false,     
        success: function(data){
        $('#divB').html(data); 
        }
    });  </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="divA">
<!-- Load divA item here -->
</div>
<div id="divB">
<!-- Load divB item here -->
</div>
```

I'm looking (and think) there's a better way to do this. Similar to this: 1 function for a div's, which automatically loads the items in (multiply) div's:

```
function loadItem(<DIV ID>) {
 $.ajax({
            url: 'load.php?type=<DIV ID>',
            cache: false,     
            success: function(data){
            $('<DIV ID>').html(data); 
            }
        }); 
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is better:

```
function loadItem(div) {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'load.php?type='+div,
      cache: false,     
      success: function(data){
         $('#'+div).html(data); 
      }
   }); 
};

$(function(){
   $('div[id^="div"]').each(function(){
      loadItem(this.id);
   });
});
```

---

What this code is doing:

1. make a global function putting function outside of doc ready.
2. In the doc ready block loop through the div whose id starts with `div` and pass that id to the function.
3. So if there are two divs then there will be two ajax calls.

---

This is a late reply:

```
$('div[class*="div"]').each(function(){ // class contains div
   loadItem(this.className.split(' ')[1]); 
});// split by ' ' space and pass the second index as arrays are 0 based index.
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this:

```
function loadItem(divId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'load.php?type=' + divId,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#' + divId).html(data);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: How to execute this function when the document loads? And automatic detect the div's?

Comment: `loadItem("divA");loadItem("divB");` call these in doc ready.